# How to make a drawer style menu similar to the one in the image

Tags: react-native

I need to recreate a menu with the same format that is in the image but I can't get the items to be grouped dynamically...

What I want to create is this:

[image]

What I have achieved is this, but I need them to be grouped in pairs without hardcode.

```
render(){
    const { menuItems } = this.state
    return(
        <LinearGradient colors={['#FFB606', '#E74C3C', '#C0392B']} style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Image source={require("../../assets/5_5_R-icon.png")} style={{width:60,height:60}}/>
                <Text style={styles.textoHeader}>Ágora <Text  style={{color:"#E67E22"}}>Club</Text></Text>
            </View>
            <ScrollView style={{paddingLeft:20}}>
                {menuItems.map((item,index) => {
                    return (<CardView 
                            icono = {item.iconType} 
                            name = {item.iconName} 
                            encabezado = {item.title}
                            onPress = {item.onPress} /> )
                })}
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearGradient>

    )
}
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Sorry if I offended you with the question, but I'm not looking for a solution to my life, much less. I just wanted to know if anyone had any idea which way I should go since I couldn't solve it on my own.

Comment: That's not a problem, we are here to help! Now, with your code, others will have direction on what you need as help.

Comment: I don't have the knowledge to help you, maybe [this article](https://reactnativecode.com/json-flatlist-with-images-and-text/) can help.